# Table View Stuck after update

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

was working in Xcode 4.6 and have a UItableview set up where the cells are populated from an array. When working in 4.6, the view behaved perfectly and was just how I liked it. After the update to 5.1.1, scrolling seems to have been enabled on the table view, the table view is loaded from the bottom of the view and the 3 populated cells at the top are not visible. Sometimes the view will rubber band and not allow me to scroll all the way back up to the top, and sometimes it won't rubber band and will let me. I am fairly new to this, but have tried messing around with auto layout, but to no avail.

Here's my code for the .h

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Manufacturers;
@end
```

Here's my code for the .m:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
// Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


_Manufacturers = @[@"1",
               @"2",
               @"3"];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return _Manufacturers.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath            *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

int row = [indexPath row];

cell.TitleLabel.text = _Manufacturers[row];


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is `TableCell` is custom cell?

Comment: Thanks of the reply. What exactly do you mean by custom cell?

Comment: Custom Cell means you are overriding the default `UITableViewCell`

Answer (score 0):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

**If you are using default `UITableViewCell`**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath            *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    }
    int row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = _Manufacturers[row];

    return cell;
}
```

**If you are using custom `TableViewCell`**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    } 

    cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'm am using the default UITableViewCell. Unfortunately the suggestion didn't work; the view is still loading at the bottom and rubber banded in position.

Comment: provide screen shot. I am not able to understand the term rubber banded.

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough reputation to post images so I made an imgur link: http://imgur.com/LgwEiA4. In the screenshot, I am clicking the mouse and dragging down. When I let go, the view bounces back up and I can no longer see the numbers at the top.

Comment: Your tableViewController is hiding the status bar. May be you have wrong set your frame anywhere. Although, tableViewController does not set a frame, so you have done some kinda mistake in your code.

Comment: The code responsible for TableViewController is all posted above. Another odd thing was that on the 2nd last build, it loaded from the bottom as usual but allowed me to freely scroll to top and the status bar then became visible. On the last build however, it returned to the previous state. Nothing was changed in between.

Answer (score 0):

TableCell is Custom than write below code..

```
 TableCell *cell = (TableCell*)[tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self options:nil];
 cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

Otherwise

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Look at this tutorial for custom cell 
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/